# Turbolinks making JavaScript not fire causing dropdowns to only work on refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, turbolinks

I have a notification dropdown menu being fired by adding a CSS class via Javascript. However, I am certain that Turbolinks is causing it to not work properly, as it seems to only work on refresh.

There is a `data-turbolinks="true"` in the `<body>` tag of the document. If I change this to `false` I get normal operation.

If I put the `data-turbolinks="false"` in the `<div>` tag of the specific links it still does not work properly.

So I am thinking I will have to change the JaveScript so it is not affected by the Turbolinks. However, I am not sure how to go about this. This is for a Laravel 5.6 app.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Notification Dropdowns
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
$(".header-notifications").each(function() {
    var userMenu = $(this);
    var userMenuTrigger = $(this).find('.header-notifications-trigger a');

    $(userMenuTrigger).on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ( $(this).closest(".header-notifications").is(".active") ) {
            close_user_dropdown();
        } else {
            close_user_dropdown();
            userMenu.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

// Closing function
function close_user_dropdown() {
    $('.header-notifications').removeClass("active");
}

// Closes notification dropdown on click outside the conatainer
var mouse_is_inside = false;

$( ".header-notifications" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
  mouse_is_inside=true;
});
$( ".header-notifications" ).on( "mouseleave", function() {
  mouse_is_inside=false;
});

$("body").mouseup(function(){
    if(! mouse_is_inside) close_user_dropdown();
});

// Close with ESC
$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        close_user_dropdown();
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this script included in a page? Is it part of a main JS file in the `<head>`? Is it run on `turbolinks:load` or $(document).ready?

Comment: It's in a `custom.js` file that's called in the `<head>` of the page. How do I tell if it's ran on `turbolinks:load` or `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Code is run on `turbolinks:load` or `$(document).ready` if you have wrapped you code in a function that is executed on either of those events e.g. `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () { CODE })`. From your response, I guess it is not, so I'm a little confused as to how this is working in the first place! Oh well, hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the script only selects the elements on the first page load, rather than on every page load. For example, calling `$(".header-notifications")` will attempt to find all the elements with a class of `.header-notifications`, however this is only run once, so when a new page is loaded with Turbolinks , the `body` gets replaced, and those selected elements no longer exist. Scripts are not executed again until a full page load, and so this script is only run once—`.header-notifications` elements are never reselected.

To fix this, the Turbolinks README recommends using event delegation:

> When possible, avoid using the turbolinks:load event to add other event listeners directly to elements on the page body. Instead, consider using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register event listeners once on document or window.

So you add your event listeners to the document or window, then choose which elements it should run on with a selector, e.g.:

```
$(document).on(
  "click", ".header-notifications-trigger a", function (event) { … }
)
```

This means that any time a `.header-notifications-trigger a` element is added to the page, the click event handler will be fired.

With that in mind, you may wish to update your script to something like:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Notification Dropdowns
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

// For convenience and to prevent unnecessary $() calls
var doc = $(document);

doc.on("click", ".header-notifications-trigger a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var user_menu = $(this).closest(".header-notifications");

    if (user_menu.is(".active")) {
        close_user_dropdown();
    } else {
        close_user_dropdown();
        user_menu.addClass('active');
    }
});

// Closing function
function close_user_dropdown() {
    $('.header-notifications').removeClass("active");
}

// Closes notification dropdown on click outside the container
var mouse_is_inside = false;

doc.on("mouseenter", ".header-notifications", function() {
    mouse_is_inside = true;
});

doc.on("mouseleave", ".header-notifications", function() {
    mouse_is_inside = false;
});

doc.on("mouseup", function(){
    if(!mouse_is_inside) close_user_dropdown();
});

// Close with ESC
doc.on("keyup", function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        close_user_dropdown();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: This solution solved the issue with the dropdown menus. But for some reason, my images are now only showing on the first visit (or refresh). Any ideas?

I'm guessing it has to do with the event delegation, as it is now affecting the whole document.

Comment: Event delegation shouldn't affect image loading. How are you loading the images? Are you seeing any errors in the JS console?

Comment: I just noticed I was having this error before I put in your updated script.  This issue is still related to turbolinks, but I will start a new thread to discuss this issue. If you have any ideas, I would love to hear them!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850497/turbolinks-prohibiting-background-images